# I want to check the type of array with spread operator in eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint

.eslintrc.js

```
 extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:@next/next/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'prettier',
 ],
```

For example, if you create an array like *array2* with the spread operator,
it will contain two different types.

It is understandable that *array2* does not cause an error because the type is not specified, but this often leads to bugs.

```
  type sample = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  };
  const array1: sample[] = [{ id: 1, name: 'name1' }, { id: 2, name: 'name2' }, { id: 3, name: 'name3' }];
  const array2 = [
    ...array1,
    ...[{ id: 4, }]
   ];
```

Is there any eslint rule to check if the array contains different types when creating *array2*?

Comment: In your case the type is implied by the values.  Array 2 will be of type `Array<sample| { id: number}>. What bugs can this leads to ? If you get eleme from `array2` - and try to use its name property - typescript will complain since name will be there only if element is of type sample.  https://tsplay.dev/mAaaBm

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no available rule for exactly this purpose.

You could hack together some combination of [ESLint's `no-restricted-syntax` rule](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax) and/or [typescript-eslint's `plugin:@typescript-eslint/typdef` rule](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/typedef) to enforce that, say, variables set to array spreads always have a type annotation. But that would also target arrays that don't change types.

To really be comprehensive you could write a [custom rule with typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules) that uses [type checking](https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules#typed-rules) to determine whether this is a case of types changing.

However, there's a good reason nobody's written a lint rule to ban this pattern. TypeScript can handle these cases well: the type checker would know `array2`'s type is `(sample | { id: number; })[]`. Also, it's reasonable that devs will have a legitimate use case for having a new array contain all the types of an old one *plus* newer types. In the example given, it's possible that `array2` would then be passed to a place that takes in `{ name?: string; id: number }[]`.

So, while you could write something like this yourself, it wouldn't be enforcing a generally accepted best practice.